A movie about a drunk pilot hired to find a girl's missing father
A girl is looking for her father who disappeared somewhere in mid-Asia (I think). The girl meets and hires a pilot, a cynical drunkard - their hate and love relationship is the major part of the story, their conversation is full of humor. There is a link to British government or secret service (the father was representing these, or was perhaps a scientist?), this part is humorous, too. There are local bad guys and tribes, a lot of fighting with air-raid against the locals (action film part?). 
Not a good film, not a famous one, probably no reason to remember it. We saw it some 10-15 years ago, and a few lines of the dialogue keep coming back continually, like the pilot shouting 'don't speak!' to the girl, and a little later, becoming interested, shouts with the same tone 'speak!'.
If any of you can identify this film? 

Perhaps High Road to China (1983) with Tom Selleck? From an online recap:

Rich woman hires drunken pilot (Selleck) to fly her to China to find her missing father.

It also features this exchange between them:

[Man:] Speak!
[Woman:] Speak?! If you or one more person tells me to speak or to not speak, or to lower my eyes, I am going to let you have it!

There's a trailer on Youtube that showcases their love-hate relationship. The entire movie is also available there, though it's dubbed in Italian.
